# Checking if index in list exists

Tags: python

*I would like to note that I'm using Discord.py and some of it's included libs.*

So I'm trying to check if an index in a list exists but I keep getting the `ValueError` saying that the index does not exist in my list.

Here's my code:

```
def deal_card(self):
        U = self.usedCards
        randCard = randchoice(list(self.cards))
        if not U: #check if it is empty
            #if it is empty, just add the card to used cards
            U.append(randCard)
        elif U.index(randCard): #check if card is already in the list
            #if it is, pick another one
            randCard = randchoice(list(self.cards))
            U.append(randCard)
        else: #check if card is not in list
            #if it is not, just add it to the used cards
            U.append(randCard)
        return randCard
```

`self.cards` is full of card names and `self.usedCards` is a list of cards alredy picked by randCard.
`hand` is my command and `P4` is one of the cards in `self.cards`

I found some solutions saying that adding a `try` block will solve the problem but I don't know how to add it in the middle of my if statement.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a note that doesn't answer your question- it would make your code a lot simpler if you simply removed the selected card from the deck every time you dealt one.  `self.shuffle = random.shuffle(self.cards); return self.shuffle.pop()`

Comment: Thank you @PaulBecotte, I'll check your suggestion :')

Answer (score 4):

`list.index()` should be used for finding the index of a list's member. To check *whether an item **is** in a list*, simply use `in`:

```
if not U:
    # do stuff
elif randCard in U:
    # do other stuff
```

Comment: Oh, did not know that. Thanks you a lot!

Answer (score 2):

This is probably a terrible way to deal your cards, because then you have the cards both in your discard pile *and* in your deck.

Why not just move the cards around?

```
import random

cards = ['H{}'.format(val) for val in range(1, 11)]
print(cards)
discard_pile = []

while cards:
    random.shuffle(cards)
    card = cards.pop()
    print('You drew a {}'.format(card))
    discard_pile.append(card)

while discard_pile:
    cards.append(discard_pile.pop())

# or

cards.extend(discard_pile)
discard_pile.clear()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the index function:

`elif randCard in U:`

Answer (score 1):

If you would still like to use the `.index` function for some reason and not follow the above suggestions you could use the `try` statement as follows:

```
try:
    c = U.index(randCard)
    randCard = randchoice(list(self.cards))
    U.append(randCard)
except ValueError:
    U.append(randCard)
```